# Json_encode php to give null string and CHECK IT (Challenge for all the json experts)

Tags: php, android, json

I'm working on my Android app and i have to check if the json string that i receive is null or not.
I'm having problems because i wrote in php this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT....");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 

if ($rows==0 or $result==null){
print(json_encode("no data"));
exit;
}
```

So in my android app i want to check if the result of the json string is "no data" or not.
On my app i receive the jsonstring in my httpsend.class where there is the classic method:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
etc..
if(is != null){

            try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result=sb.toString();
```

Now if there aren't rows in the php file, if i do:

```
Log.i("result from php: ",result);
```

I get "no data" so ok.
But when i give this string value with the:

```
return result;
```

to my MainActivity where there is:

```
String risjson=null;
HttpSend httas = new HttpSend(values...not important);
    httas.execute();

    try {
        risjson=httas.get();
        System.out.print("value is"+risjson); //i get "no data" in the Log

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    //following one answer (but by now it doesn't work)
    if (risjson.equals("\"no data\"")){
        System.out.print("THERE AREN'T INFORMATIONS");
    }
```

And my program doesn't go in this if! Why?
Remember, the app works fine with right values. (so rows in php isn't zero)

If i do this:

```
for(int i=0;i<risjson.length();i++){
        System.out.println(risjson.charAt(i));
    }

    System.out.println(risjson.length());
```

I get:

```
"
n
o

d
a
t
a
"
11
```

"no data" are 9 characters, what are the other two characters? This is very very strange.

I saw that if in my php file i do:

```
if ($righe==0 or $result==null){
print(json_encode(1));
exit;
}
```

and then the same stemps i get:

```
1   //what i get from risjson
3  //lenght
```

So two characters here too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code on php side:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT....");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 

if ($rows==0 or $result==null)
{
    print(json_encode(array("data"=>"no data")));
    exit;
}
```

Then client side(Android/Iphone/Web) guys will receive this kind of response(Json object)

```
    {
    "data": "nodata"
    }
```

Comment: I choose this answer because it solved the problem, however remains the mystery of the two characters. In if you show your json object you get: "data": "nodata" so 16 characters, but if you count the lenght you get 18.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with android, but the problem is likely that your string is not `no data`. When you use `json_encode` to encode your string, the result will be `"no data"` so you would need to check for the quotes as well.

In php you would use `'"no data"'` or `"\"no data\""` so you have to look for the equivalent in android.

Comment: Yes, it should be `risjson.equals("\"no data\"")`

Comment: @JustinPowell Thanks, sounds very logical, I just wasn't sure :-)

Comment: i tried "risjson.equals("\"no data\"")" but it doesn't work. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @tittarella Have you checked what your string contains exactly?

Comment: I'm checking with Log.i, i'm getting "no data".

Comment: check risjson and see what it holds

Comment: There is a better way to check risjson?

Comment: breakpoints, Log, System.out.println, toast, it doesn't matter what you choose so long as you can see what it is

Comment: if i do System.out.print("value is"+risjson); after risjson=httas.get(); i get on the Log: TEXT: value is "no data".